# Caliburn Micro - Update UI with data from a BackgroudTask running in ShellViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have WPF Application with 5 views and one of the views is to show the activity of the BackgroundTask running every 1 hourin ShellViewModel.cs.

I created a global variable in App.xaml.cs to store the BackgroundTask status for each progress.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string RunStatus { get; set; }
}
```

In the ActivityViewModel.cs, I created a public variable (RunStatus) and bound it to a Label in the XAML.

I see the updated RunStatus (in UI) when I refresh the View.

```
public class ActivityViewModel : Screen
{
    public string RunStatus
    {
        get;
        set{ NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RunStatus); }
    }

    public ActivityViewModel()
    {
        RunStatus = App.RunStatus;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use NotifyOfPropertyChange() to update the UI with value from App.RunStatus when the value in App.RunStatus changes without refreshing the view?

Answer (score -2):

You need to update the `string RunStatus` on the `UI` thread.

One way is using the Dispatcher, for which Caliburn provide an IDispatcher for.

```
    public class ActivityViewModel : Screen
    {
        private string _runStatus;

        public string RunStatus
        {
            get {return _runStatus}
            set
            {
                _runStatus = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RunStatus);
            }
        }

        public ActivityViewModel(IDispatcher dispatcher)
        {
            dispatcher.BeginExecuteOnUIThread(() =>
            {
                RunStatus = App.RunStatus;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
    public class ActivityViewModel : Screen
    {
        private readonly IDispatcher _dispatcher;
        private string _runStatus;

        public string RunStatus
        {
            get {return _runStatus}
            set
            {
                _dispatcher.BeginExecuteOnUIThread(() =>
                {
                    _runStatus = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RunStatus);
                });
            }
        }

        public ActivityViewModel(IDispatcher dispatcher)
        {
            _dispatcher = dispatcher;
        }

        public void SomeOtherMethod()
        {
            RunStatus = App.RunStatus;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is IDispatcher part of Caliburn only? I could not find it in Caliburn Micro.

Comment: Caliburn automatically ensures property change notifications happen on the UI thread. It also doesn't provide an IDispatcher but uses Execute.OnUIThread for instance.

Comment: Nigel, could you please show the updates needed to be made to the above code to make it work. Thanks!